# generate url in module and outside of module in Yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I have a module with the name of admin. when i generate link with Url::to(['admin/assignment']) outside of module it's work and create this link:

```
http://localhost:8080/test/backend/web/admin/assignment.html
```

but when this url generated in running current module it's create this linke and doesn't work

```
http://localhost:8080/test/backend/web/admin/admin/assignment.html
```

how can i create a rule in route (UrlManager) for control problem like this!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try `Url::to(['/admin/assignment'])` (with the leading /): routes without the leading / are interpreted as relative to the current module.

Comment: Let's say theses urls are being generated in the layout and used in navbar.. how can the url know when some links are from outside the module if the module is using the same layout?